# setting up the UI defaults

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to figure how to use angularjs and even after some reading i still think i got it wrong.

i have some UI values that need to be loaded and some default behaviour for some buttons that i want to define.

i have used the following code:

```
var webAdmin = angular.module('webAdmin', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, dataStore) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', { templateUrl: '/app/views/dashboard.html', controller: 'DashboardController' })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]) // end config
    .run([
        function() {


        }
    ]); // end run

webAdmin
    .controller('sidebarMenuController', function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.collapseSidebar = function() {
            $element.parent().parent().toggleClass('sidebar-collapsed');
        }

        var lis = $element[0].querySelectorAll('#main-menu > li.has-sub');
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; ++i) {
            var li = lis[i];
            var ul = angular.element(li.querySelector('ul'));
            var el = angular.element(li.querySelector('a'));
            el.bind('click', function(e) {
                angular.element(li).toggleClass('opened');
                ul.toggleClass('visible');
            });
        }
    });
```

as you can see, i applied the default buttons behaviour in the controller,
but i got a feeling that is the wrong place for it, is it?

also, where would i load my UI values? the UI values are "global" (used within the app and many controllers should be able to access it.)
for example, i plan to load the menu items dynamically (based on user permissions), where should i load them?

**EDIT:**

loading UI values: Either by using `$resource` or `$http` to load external json
if its not clear from the code, i need a collapse button for the menu and similar functionality.

**EDIT2:**
The HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar-menu" ng-controller="sidebarMenuController">
    <header class="logo-env">

        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" width="160" height="50">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- logo collapse icon -->

        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <a href="#" ng-click="collapseSidebar()" class="sidebar-collapse-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- open/close menu icon (do not remove if you want to enable menu on mobile devices) -->
        <div class="sidebar-mobile-menu visible-xs">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

    </header>
    <ul id="main-menu">

        <li id="search">
            <input type="text" name="q" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="button" ng-click="searchClick()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </li>

        <li class="has-sub">
            <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span>Reports</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span>New Report</span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><span>Open Report</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i><span>Save Report</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="logo-vert hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="/images/logo.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

Plunker link as requested:

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/oWmZSE5MXw4e9CpLMABd)

Comment: If you are using JQuery in Angular then you are most likely doing something wrong. What does your HTML look like that needs behavior on it?

Comment: @MatthewGreen - i do not use JQuery (except JQuery light which is part of angular). also, i need help on where to implement the `$resource` call to get the initial values, so i am not asking for a review of my code, but to understand where to implement.

Comment: Sorry about that. The `$element` line looked like JQuery when I glanced over it. Also, you don't mention anything in your question about `$resource`. You may want to update your question with information about that.

Comment: added at the end for reference (since im not sure which one would be the right one to use)

Comment: First, can you show your HTML? Second, is it possible that you use ng-class and ng-click to modify classes on click, as opposed to using .bind ?

Comment: @Dementic For what it is worth, I wasn't entirely wrong about you using JQuery in your code. [See the doc for angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: @MatthewGreen - i think you missed the second part of that statement '. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."'

Comment: @SoluableNonagon - yes, i do use `ng-click`, i am not sure of the correct way and `ng-click` seemed the right choice. unless you can tell me differently. as you can see in my code, i also used `bind` but am unsure if either is correct.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker of your code? http://plnkr.co/edit/ufjSYH7jhy7Gn64cFoHa here is a blank template to get you started

Comment: Yeah, this needs to be done in a directive, with a directive you have the power to inject a service as well! So, a controller is just meant to delegate data to the view, a directive works more on the html rendering based on a particular model data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like you might start with [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). Here are some pointers from me:

### Adjusting View and Going Up the DOM Tree

When updating the view based on user interaction, you should almost never need to use the `jQueryLite` functions (outside definitions of your own directives). Additionally, to keep your code modular, you shouldn't walk up the DOM tree from your controller's `$element`. So, if you want to implement sidebar toggling, you'd go about it this way:

1. define `sidebar.isVisible` on the outer scope (so that it is visible from the elements you need to adjust),
2. use `ng-show` directive to show/hide the sidebar based on your variable, and

   ```
   <div class="sidebar" ng-show="sidebar.isVisible">...</div>
   ```
3. change just the value of that variable from the inner scope.

   ```
   $scope.collapseSidebar = function () {
       $scope.sidebar.isVisible = false;
   };
   ```

### Binding event handlers

When binding event handlers, do *not* use `jQueryLite` functions like `.bind()`, if you can help it. Not only do they call the handlers outside AngularJS `$digest` cycle (which means you need to call their code inside an `$apply()`), but they also lead to much less transparency in your code.

For example, when binding to `click` on your `<a>` elements, use simply

```
<a ng-click="someHandler()">...</a>
```

or

```
<a ng-click="someHandler($event)">...</a>
```

if you want to get the event data. Your handler should, again, just change some data on scope, not manually modify element classes, etc.

### Loading and Storing Global Data

When loading data to be used across the whole application, you could simply do:

```
angular.module('...', [...]).run(['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    $http(...).success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.someDataVar = data;
    });
}]);
```

and see your data across all scopes. However, this pollutes your `$rootScope` needlessly. Instead, you could just create an outer controller encapsulating your whole view, and put the data on its scope. Additionally, you might want to store your global data in a global service, so that it can be injected into other services that aren't bound to any scope.

Comment: God bless you for the link.

Comment: and again for the explanation.